# What's the meaning of the word "to"?

Tags: grammar

From VOA:

> Once enacted, the bill would give the nation a two-year reprieve from the budget wars that have consumed Congress in recent years. It reduces across-the board cuts ***to*** federal spending and, at the same time pares the deficit, earning the backing of Republicans like Congressman Paul Ryan.

What's the meaning of the word "to" in the paragraph above? It seems to have some meaning of "relating to". Can you give me some more examples of its kind? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form “cuts to X” means the same as “decreases in X”, with *cuts* and *decreases* both acting as nouns.  That is, the paragraph says that planned reductions in federal spending will be less deep; the decreases will be reduced.

Comment: … similar to, for example, “a blow to the head” (referring to a physical assault, such as a punch by a fist or possibly an attack with a weapon).